# DynamoDB: query for objects so nested array of object contains object that has an array with some value

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have products list which I want to query by primary key and condition. The condition is that inner Options array, contains at least one object that satisfies that following: it’s AvailableDates array contains a given value (e.g 2023-01-01). Here is the data structure:

```
Products
[
    {
       CityId – primary key
       ProductId – sort key     
       Options – Array of Option:
       [
          {
             AvailableDates: [ 2023-01-01, 2023-01-02, etc ]
          }
       ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`FilterExpression="contains(Options[0].AvailableDates, '2023-01-01')"`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Attributes.html#Expressions.Attributes.NestedAttributes

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html

Comment: What you are suggesting seem true if I want to check just the first element.  In my case Options is array and I need to check if one of the options element contains AvailableDates array that has '2023-01-01' in it.

Comment: You cannot loop through all items in a list looking for a string value within a map.